# @Transactional testing fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-test

I try to create testcases for `@Transactional`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TransactionalAnnotationTest {
    public static final BigDecimal PROD_ID = new BigDecimal(1234);

    @PersistenceContext
    HibernateEntityManager em;


    @Test
    public final void testTransactionIsolation() {
        String original = em.find(ProductImpl.class, PROD_ID).getDescription();
        // original = "Foo"
        updateTx(original);
    }

    @Transactional
    public final void updateTx(String original) {
        ProductImpl product = em.find(ProductImpl.class, PROD_ID);
        product.setDescription("Bar");
        whatIsInDB(original);
    }

    private void whatIsInDB(String original) {
        String sameTxDescription = em.find(ProductImpl.class, PROD_ID).getDescription();
        assert !sameTxDescription.equals(original);
    }
}
```

It fail! Should the second `em.find` not return a Product with "Bar"?

Comment: I think you meant 'a Product with "Bar"'

Comment: Am i right that `@Transactional` is for Spring-Managed-Beans that are Autowired only???

Comment: I think you are right. you can work around this (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj) but you may consider it to be too complicated for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm, i got it to work.

1. To test Transactions: a simple `em.flush()` is all i need (thanks to @TaoufikMohdit for the idea). If there is no transaction, `flush()` throws a `TransactionRequiredException`!
2. `@Transactional` is for Spring-Managed-Beans only. So i create a Service:

   ```
   @Service
   public class BasicTransactionalService {
     @PersistenceContext
     HibernateEntityManager em;

     @Transactional
     public void testFlushInTransactional() {
       em.flush();
     }

     @Deprecated
     public void testFlushOutsideTransactional() {
       em.flush();
     }

     @Transactional
     public void testFlushSubroutineTransactional() {
       testFlushOutsideTransactional();
     }
   }
   ```
3. I changed the Tests to:

   ```
   @Autowired
   BasicTransactionalService bean;

   @Test
   public void testTransactionIsolation() {
     bean.testFlushInTransactional();
   }

   @Test(expected = TransactionRequiredException.class)
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public void testThrowsTransactionRequiredException() {
     bean.testFlushOutsideTransactional();
   }

   @Test
   public void testTransactionalSubroutine(){
     bean.testFlushSubroutineTransactional();
   }
   ```

Now it works fine.

BTW This is my `app-config.xml`

```
<beans>
  <bean class="BasicTransactionalService" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />
  <tx:annotation-driven />
<beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly flushing the context after setting the "description" field

```
product.setDescription("Bar");
em.flush();
whatIsInDB(original);
```

Comment: No, `flush()` writes to db. `whatIsInDB` would make no sense after `flush`.

Comment: Sorry, I just got your test meaning now. I would be curious to know what the flush mode is (em.getFlushMode()), if it's not AUTO or ALWAYS, this could explain the test failure.

Comment: `em.getFlushMode()` returns `AUTO` in `testTransactionIsolation`, `AUTO` in `updateTx` and `AUTO` in `whatIsInDB`.